# Notice: register_rest_route was called incorrectly. The REST API route definition for yoast/v1/get_head is missing the required permission_callback a

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

The site I'm working on is showing this issue on the posts/pages on the dashboard.

"Notice: register_rest_route was called incorrectly. The REST API route definition for yoast/v1/get_head is missing the required permission_callback argument. For REST API routes that are intended to be public, use __return_true as the permission callback. "

I just updated to WP 5.7.2 and the Yoast SEO Premium is version 14.4.1.

Does anyone know how to address this?

Comment: I don’t have premium installed anywhere, is that the latest? The free version is at 16 and that change was addressed a while back

Comment: I think it is, it deosn't have any call to update. I'm wondering if Yoast SEO Premium is separate from the other one.

Answer (score 7):

Add **'permission_callback' => '__return_true'** as argument to the function. Below are example code you can follow

```
register_rest_route( 'plugin_name/api', '/token/', array(
    'methods' => 'YOUR_METHOD',
    'callback' => 'CALLBACK_FUNCTION_NAME',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
));
```

Answer (score 1):

The **permission_callback** is required since WordPress 5.5, maybe if you update Yoast SEO the issue can get fixed, and if you can't update, I'll recommend disabling the WP_DEBUG from your **wp-config.php** file like this: `define('WP_DEBUG', false)`

See [REST API changes in WordPress 5.5 - section 'permission_callback'](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/22/rest-api-changes-in-wordpress-5-5/#callback)

Comment: Please add external sources to back-up your statements. See [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)